# Duplicate items in Set

Tags: collections, kotlin

In Kotlin, I have a `MutableSet` of a data class. The data class does not override `equals()` or `hashCode()`. I've been encountering bugs involving duplicate objects in the set, and I noticed that calling `foo.containsAll(foo)` returns `false` for the set.

I went through each item in the set and only a handful return `false` for `foo.contains(foo.toList()[i])`. For those that do, calling `foo.toList()[i] == foo.toList()[i]` returns `true`. So, equality checking works.

What is going on here?

Comment: Struggling to repro this: http://ideone.com/n8ydzW.  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am strugging to come up with one. However, I have found a workaround. Using `foo.all { a -> foo.any { b -> a == b } }` is working as a substitute for `containsAll()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only way this is possible (short of reflection, etc.) is if your data class contains something mutable and an instance changing state after being added to the set, etc. e.g.

```
data class Foo(var int: Int = 0)
data class Bar(val string: String, val foo: Foo = Foo())

val bars = mutableSetOf<Bar>()
bars += Bar("")
bars += Bar("")

println(bars.containsAll(bars)) // true

bars.first().foo.int = 12

println(bars.containsAll(bars)) // false
```

This is because the result of `hashCode()` is being used in the set to identify it but if the state changes in an instance of your data class then it will likely have a different hash value causing issues like this.

In general elements in sets and keys in maps should be immutable to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you! This is the problem I am running into. It's still weird to have `foo.containsAll(foo)` return false, though.

Comment: Yes, that is simply how hashes work though and is why you simply shouldn't use mutable objects in a hash (note that mutable values in a map are fine just not keys).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating set like this

```
setOf(
    Coordinates(it.x - 1, it.y),
    Coordinates(it.x - 1, it.y - 1),
    Coordinates(it.x - 1, it.y + 1),

    Coordinates(it.x, it.y),
    Coordinates(it.x, it.y - 1),
    Coordinates(it.x, it.y + 1),

    Coordinates(it.x + 1, it.y),
    Coordinates(it.x + 1, it.y - 1),
    Coordinates(it.x + 1, it.y + 1),
)
```

where class looked like this

```
data class Coordinates(val x: Int, val y: Int)
```

and I was getting duplicates even after I used override on hashCode and equals methods, nothing helped.

The solution that worked in the end was creating a list and converting to set, there was no need to override anything.

```
listOf( ... ).toSet()
```